# Re evaluate django query after changes done to database

Tags: python, django, dry, django-queryset

I got this long queryset statement on a view

```
    contributions = user_profile.contributions_chosen.all()\
    .filter(payed=False).filter(belongs_to=concert)\
    .filter(contribution_def__left__gt=0)\
    .filter(contribution_def__type_of='ticket')
```

That i use in my template

```
context['contributions'] = contributions
```

And later on that view i make changes(add or remove a record) to the table contributions_chosen and if i want my context['contributions'] updated i need to requery the database with the same lenghty query.

```
contributions = user_profile.contributions_chosen.all()\
.filter(payed=False).filter(belongs_to=concert)\
.filter(contribution_def__left__gt=0)\
.filter(contribution_def__type_of='ticket')
```

And then again update my context

```
context['contributions'] = contributions
```

So i was wondering if theres any way i can avoid repeating my self, to reevaluate the contributions so it actually reflects the real data on the database.
Ideally i would modify the queryset contributions and its values would be updated, and at the same time the database would reflect this changes, but i don't know how to do this.

UPDATE:
This is what i do between the two
    context['contributions'] = contributions

I add a new contribution object to the contributions_chosen(this is a m2m relation),

```
contribution = Contribution.objects.create(kwarg=something,kwarg2=somethingelse)
user_profile.contributions_chosen.add(contribution) 
contribution.save()
user_profile.save()
```

And in some cases i delete a contribution object
    contribution = user_profile.contributions_chosen.get(id=1)
    user_profile.contributions_chosen.get(id=request.POST['con
    contribution.delete()

As you can see i'm modifying the table contributions_chosen so i have to reissue the query and update the context.
What am i doing wrong?

UPDATE
After seeing your comments about evaluating, i realize i do eval the queryset i do
len(contributions) between context['contribution'] and that seems to be problem.
I'll just move it after the database operations and thats it, thanks guy.

Comment: Seems you have not evaluated the queryset `contributions`, thus there is no need to worry about updating it because it still has not fetched data from DB. `QuerySet` is lazy-evaluated thus it has nothing related to DB rows until been evaluated.

Answer (score 4):

*update*
Seems you have not evaluated the queryset `contributions`, thus there is no need to worry about updating it because it still has not fetched data from DB.

Can you post code between two `context['contributions'] = contributions` lines? Normally before you evaluate the queryset `contributions` (for example by iterating over it or calling its `__len__()`), it does not contain anything reading from DB, hence you don't have to *update* its content.

To re-evaluate a queryset, you could

```
# make a clone
contribution._clone()
# or any op that makes clone, for example
contribution.filter()

# or clear its cache
contribution._result_cache = None

# you could even directly add new item to contribution._result_cache, 
# but its could cause unexpected behavior w/o carefulness
```

Comment: The docs specifically [suggest using `all()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#all) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you can avoid re-evaluating the query, but one way to save some repeated statements in your code would be to create a dict with all those filters and to specify the `filter` args as a dict:

```
query_args = dict(
    payed=False,
    belongs_to=concert,
    contribution_def__left__gt=0,
    contribution_def__type_of='ticket',
)
```

and then

```
contributions = user_profile.contributions_chosen.filter(**query_args)
```

**This just removes some repeated code, but does not solve the repeated query.** If you need to change the args, just handle `query_args` as a normal Python dict, it is one after all :)

Comment: In the code he provides he doesn't seem to evaluate the query anyway. The query gets evaluated when he iterates over it in the template or when he does other stuff that triggers query evaluation, as documented at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated